# How to find the coordinates of a pixel with a specific value in a raster data in R

Tags: r

I am a beginner in R and this is a basic question but I have a raster with values ranging from 0 to 1. I want to know which pixel has the value 1 or which pixels have a value higher than 0.8. I tried to find it with which() function:

```
> r <-myRaster
> which(values(r) == 1)
> [1] 12556
```

This gives me the pixel number but i want to know which latitude and longitude this pixel corresponds to. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for `xyFromCell`.

Let's create a simple reproducible raster:

```r
library(raster)

set.seed(1)

myraster <- raster(matrix(sample(100), nrow = 10))
```

We can find the co-ordinates where the cell value is 1 by doing:

```r
coords_at_1 <-  xyFromCell(myraster, which(myraster[] == 1))

coords_at_1
#>         x    y
#> [1,] 0.05 0.75
```

And to show this, let's mark a red point where the raster equals 1:

```
plot(myraster)
points(coords_at_1, cex = 3, pch = 15, col = "red")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-11-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer. I have one more question about this function. Lets say that I found the coordinates of the pixel. Now I have another raster with same resolution and extent. I want to select the pixel in the second raster with the coordinates from the first raster and convert its value to NA. I tried myraster[coords_at_1] but it did not work. How can I do this?

Comment: @user14316891 `myraster[cellFromXY(myraster, coords_at_1)]`

Comment: Great! Thank you for all the help